# Searching a value in array not working

Tags: php, arrays

One of my array value contains

```
$all_data_array = Array
(
    [0] => 'General Information'
    [1] => 'Brand'
    [2] => '<p><div style="bolor:#000000;"><li>Product Details</li></div></p>'
)
```

.

And I want to search for key of the value in Array, where array value has text "Product Details" in it, wrapped around some html data.
I wrote the following code, but it's not working. Can someone help?

```
<?php echo $new_key = array_search('Product Details', $all_data_array); ?>
```

Comment: Can you please show how is your `$all_data_array` array looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_search` need the string value be exactly the same.

You could just use a loop in your case.

```
foreach ($all_data_array as $key => $value) {
  if (strpos($value, 'Product Details') !== false) {
    $new_key = $key;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_filter` lets you specify a custom function to do the searching. In your case, a simple function that uses `strpos()` to check if your search string is present:

Answer (score 0):

array_search, looks for the exact match, third element of array $all_data_array has other characters(Here html tags) apart from "Product Details";